# File Upload in KoaJS

Tags: node.js, file-upload, koa

I'm trying to upload files using the code from example. But it's not working.

In the controller I wrote the code

```
var parse = require('co-busboy');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var parts = parse(this);
var part;

while (part = yield parts) {
    var stream = fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/' + part.filename);
    part.pipe(stream);
    console.log('uploading %s -> %s', part.filename, stream.path);
}
```

But when I upload images in the console I only get new uploading location. But on new location images are not saving.

Any Solution?

Thanks in Advance,

Nixon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer. I just had to remove '/' before the 'tmp'.
So the code is like this

```
while (part = yield parts) {
var stream = fs.createWriteStream('tmp/' + part.filename);
part.pipe(stream);
console.log('uploading %s -> %s', part.filename, stream.path);
}
```

Comment: I believe you got this example from (https://github.com/koajs/examples/blob/master/upload/index.js). I was confused as well so created a pull request now, let's see what happens (https://github.com/koajs/examples/pull/40)

Comment: You do know that it likely was actually writing your file out just fine, just not where you thought it was going to? There is a module for cross platform temporary storage built into node rather than using `/tmp/`.